# /proc/config.gz is of 0 bytes

Tags: linux, files, kernel, proc

I have an Android TV stck
I compiled Linux for IT from https://github.com/Galland/rk3x_kernel_3.0.36

But when I booted that Image I found /proc/config.gz is of 0 bytes

can some please explain how the command line params from .config file in kernel source get mounted to /proc.
I mean what goes in the background??

Comment: See also [What happens when I run the command cat /proc/cpuinfo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121702/what-happens-when-i-run-the-command-cat-proc-cpuinfo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files in `/proc` do not have a file size in general, and are shown as having 0 size in `ls -l`, but you can read data from them anyway (see `man 5 proc`).

Try, for example:

`zcat /proc/config.gz | wc`

or:

```
$ ls -l /proc/cmdline
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug  4 10:16 /proc/cmdline
```

Looks empty. But:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline | wc
      1       5     114
```

it contains data. Let's see:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=fc48808f-8f06-47fc-a1fe-5d08ee9e0a50 ro noirqdebug nomodeset
```

feels like a normal file - except if you want to do anything special, like reading by blocks, seek(), or loking at the size.

In case you can not read `/proc/config.gz`, there is a file that normally contains the same:

`less /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config`

See [`man proc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/proc) for details.

Comment: ever so thrifty. It is admirable.

Comment: Hey, I did not recycle that, like last time :)

Comment: I know, and I deleted the comment. But *recycling* is good for *the planet*.

Comment: zcat /proc/config.gz worked for me .....
Thanks a lot