# Do all virtual files have a size of 0 in Linux?

Tags: linux, proc

So far, I have only seen virtual files with a size of 0, for example the virtual file `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` has a size of 0.

But do all virtual files have a size of 0, or are there some virtual files that the kernel shows the size of?

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority have no size, but there are a few exceptions, which you can see with

```
find /proc -type f \! -empty -ls 2>/dev/null
```

They are `/proc/kcore` and various PCI files.

See [/proc/config.gz is of 0 bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148258/86440) and [What happens when I run the command cat /proc/cpuinfo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121702/86440) for related information.