# No system call when malloc after free

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-audit

While I was playing a little with kernel audit system, I made a small C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        void *t;
        while(1){
                t = malloc(1);
                free(t);

        }
        return 0;
}
```

And applied the following filters to audit:

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open,openat -F exit=-EACCES -F key=access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open,openat -F exit=-EACCES -F key=access
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S brk
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S brk
```

After compiling and running, I noticed that `sys_brk` wasn't showing up in the audit log.
Furthermore it didn't also appear in `strace`, even tho `malloc` was called (checked with ltrace).
Lastly I removed the free and the calls to `sys_brk` started showing up.

What is causing this type of behaviour? Does glibc make some kind of optimization in `malloc` and `free` functions to prevent useless syscalls?

TL;DR: `free` followed by `malloc` makes neither call the kernel. Why?

Comment: It might use brk () or mmap ()

Comment: Neither appeared in strace

Comment: malloc() and free() are both library functions, not system calls, and a free() doesn't immediately return the freed memory to the system (which isn't even possible to do with less than 1 mempage granularity), but is putting it on a free blocks list. This question is similar to "why isn't every putchar(3) resulting in a write(2)?"

Comment: I think you didn't read the question. The problem, as explained, is brk not being called when malloc is....

Comment: You haven't explained why you assume that `brk()` has to be called every time `malloc()` is called (or every 10 or 100 times, it doesn't matter). In the second case, the program break has to be adjusted with `brk()` because you're leaking memory (allocating memory without freeing it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program starts with an initial heap, and your one byte allocation fits within that heap. When you immediately free the allocated memory, the heap never needs to grow so you never see a corresponding system call.

See [How quickly/often are process memory measurements updated in the kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329758/86440) for a similar experiment.

Comment: Nice explanation. Didn't think about that. Thanks!