# What is the region of memory allocated by malloc()?

Tags: linux, c, posix, pthreads

I was writing a multi-threaded C program using `pthread` library. The program calls the `malloc()` from a thread and the main-thread. When I inspected the memory address returned by `malloc()`, the address returned by the `malloc()` in the main-thread was usual address (like 0x80874a0) which is the address of heap section of the program. But the address returned by the `malloc()` in another thread (created by `pthread_create()`) is kind of unusual the address was high in the address space (0x7ffa87000a60 looking kind of like address in stack section). After analyzing the address of some stack variable of that thread, it looks like the address returned by the `malloc()` is near the stack for that thread.

I am confused because as far as I know the **heap** section of a program is shared by all threads in that program, so any call to `malloc()` should return addresses kind of close together. It should return addresses starting from one address. But for sure it isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the very definition of it, what you get from malloc is "heap". So, all of this is heap.

GNU libc's `malloc` documents itself as doing this (`man malloc`) in "arenas":

> To scalably handle memory allocation in multithreaded applications, glibc creates additional memory allocation arenas if mutex contention is detected.  Each arena is a large region of memory that is internally allocated by the system (using `brk(2)` or `mmap(2)`), and managed with its own mutexes.

> I am confused becase as far as I know the heap section of a program is shared by all threads in that program,

"Heap" generally is not my favorite term. It conflates separate concepts:

- (*Heap* is a data structure. Whether or not the memory management data structures in your kernel and/or created by `malloc` are heaps is not a given (they're usually not.) So, that's already a source of confusion.)
- *Heap* in operating systems with memory protection and virtual addresses refers to some region of the process space from which `malloc` takes a piece, notes it internally as being used (be it in a separate table, heap,…, or in a header before the beginning of the piece itself). As such, it's an ambiguous term. You can extend your processes virtual memory using `brk` as you like, without actually occupying physical memory. So, you can for example get yourself an extra 10 GB of space, and then use two different start addresses separated by 5 GB within that to have two different regions to allocate memory from. Is that one heap, two regions? Two regions, each on their own heap? Literature doesn't agree on that. What if just extending the end of my virtual memory space with `brk`, I decide to `mmap` unbacked memory somewhere, in two places? Are these then two heaps?

So, it really boils down to what "heap" means in **your** book, and what your specific `malloc` implementation does to actually reserve memory.

Answer (score 2):

For “large” allocations (large when compared to the page size), the GNU C library’s implementation of `malloc` [uses `mmap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-GNU-Allocator.html). That’s probably what you’re seeing here — the first allocation is handled using `malloc`’s arenas, the second using `mmap` (which uses addresses that are much higher).

See [How quickly/often are process memory measurements updated in the kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329758/86440) for an illustration of this behaviour.