# How reliable is the process data in /proc/*?

Tags: process, proc

I know that `/proc` gets generated on the fly, but I'm curious, if `fork`, `evecve` and process termination are guaranteed to be seen by all other processes *immediately*.

Obviously, the kernel knows it all, but I'd like to see explicitly stated, that the *presented* information is really always up to date. I could imagine the kernel might choose to minimize synchronization overhead or whatever by batching updates to some internal structures used for `/proc`.

This sounds improbable, but there is a problem with our code, which could be explained by this. It's misusing reading `/proc` for a "single instance check" (which is racy and IMHO plain wrong). When two instances get started nearly concurrently, then it obviously can happen, that each sees itself and the other instance and both complain. However, it looks like the opposite problem (no instance complains) happens to our customers.

## Clarification

The [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) states that "For making accounting scalable, RSS related information are handled in an asynchronous manner and the value may not be very precise". Analogously **the whole process list could be handled asynchronously** and that's what I'd like to see clearly confuted. An

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249032/581205) says that

> Most (if not all) files in the /proc filesystem are special files, their content at any given moment reflect the actual OS/kernel data at that very moment, they're not files with contents periodically updated.

But it doesn't say if "most" includes what I care about, nor does it claim to be an *authoritative* answer.

Comment: @dsstorefile Thanks, I missed [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74716/5116). Maybe I should delete my question? Still, I'd be happy about an *autoritative* link.

Comment: Nothing more authoritative than the links to the code in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121884/70524

Comment: I have flag duplicates of my question because, I'm not 100% sur e about what your asking but I really feel like I answer it already.

Comment: @Kiwy To clarify what I'm asking: The [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) states that "For making accounting scalable, RSS related information are **handled in an asynchronous manner and the value may not be very precise"**. Analogously the whole process list could be handled asynchronously and that's what I'd like to see clearly confuted.  But I guess, the fact that nobody shares my concern is a strong enough indication of the data being always up to date.

Comment: @maaartinus please edit your question with this bit of information and I will consider a reopen vote. Also you could consult this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249032/1195001

Comment: Also read this one because it might qualify as duplicate : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74713/53092